# Check if point exists within a polygon in react-native-maps?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, polygon, react-native-maps

I have an API that returns an array of latitudes and longitudes that define the boundaries of an area on a map(polygon).

[image: an example of a polygon]

In my react-native app, I have react-native-maps installed. How do I check if the user's location is in the polygon returned by the api?

I know this can be achieved with google maps web with the `containsLocation()` function. Does a function like that exist for `react-native-maps`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`react-native-maps` doesn't expose that function, but there are two packages that I'm aware of that can help you:

1. [react-native-geo-fencing](https://github.com/surialabs/react-native-geo-fencing) that does the same as the google maps utility you've mentioned.
2. [react-native-geo-fence](https://github.com/toystars/react-native-geo-fence#usage) handles location checks for you and exposes events you can hook into.

Comment: both options are pretty old at this point. Like @ItWillDo is mentioning below **geolib** is the best alternative offering `isPointInPolygon(point, polygon)`

Answer (score 10):

For anyone still looking for an easier alternative (or for `Circle` support just like I needed it), look into using `geolib`: https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib.

Installation is simple and straightforward:

`$yarn add geolib`

Afterward in your React Native project, import it using:

`import geolib from 'geolib'`

And then just use the API as explained in the README.md.

Comment: I get this in android `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property isPointInPolygon of undefined, js engine: hermes`

Answer (score 2):

[`geolib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib)
is the best solution.
`react-native-geo-fencing` is deprecated and it cause more errors to your project and also
`react-native-geo-fence` is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

My code to check if lat, lon is inside object of many polys. It returns true if coordinate is inside one of the polygons.

```
 isInsidePoly = (lat, lon, multiPolycoords) => {
// ray-casting algorithm based on
// https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html/pnpoly.html

var x = lat,
  y = lon;

var inside = false;
multiPolycoords.map(poly => {
  vs = poly;
  for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
    var xi = vs[i].latitude,
      yi = vs[i].longitude;
    var xj = vs[j].latitude,
      yj = vs[j].longitude;

    var intersect =
      yi > y != yj > y && x < ((xj - xi) * (y - yi)) / (yj - yi) + xi;
    if (intersect) inside = !inside;
  }
});

return inside;
```

};